# Displaying Distance in Miles for Elevation Profile using Profile Tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, units, profile

I am attempting to generate an elevation profile in QGIS 3.2.2, with elevation in feet, and distance in miles, using Profile Tool.  I have managed to convert my DEM files to feet, and the elevation of the path displays correctly in feet in the Profile Tool window.  The distance continues to display in meters.

I have set my project preferences to use Miles for distance measurement, but no matter what I do, what setting I click, I cannot get the distance on the x axis to display in feet in Profile Tool.

I've also tried the qProf plugin with the same results; elevation displays in feet, distance in meters.

I feel like I'm overlooking something simple.  Is there an easy way to change the distance units, either in the data, in QGIS itself, or using the Profile Tool?

Comment: what projection is your data in? are the distance units of that projection feet?

Comment: After posting this question, and even more googling and searching, I finally stumbled across the State Plane CRS in the settings in QGIS.  So now I have the distance in feet in the profile tool generator!   Is there any way to make it calculate in miles instead, or am I going to have to do some intense graphical editing anyway?

Comment: please post how you solved this question for the benefit of others

Comment: I would still like to be able to display the data in the Profile Tool in miles, but I can at least more easily figure out where, between 5000 feet and 6000 feet, etc. 5280 feet is...

Comment: as an answer below please

Answer (score 1):

So, there are literally dozens of CRS's in QGIS.  In the Project Properties, CRS tab, the CRS I found is under the Lambert Conformal Conic list, and if you scroll way down, you will eventually find NAD83 data for all the US states in both feet and meters, for different areas of the states.  I found Pennsylvania North (ftUS) in the list.